# Ajax request returns a 404 but URL works fine

Tags: ajax, cakephp

I'm doing an jQuery ajax call to an XML page in my CakePHP site. For some strange reason CakePHP returns a 404 error when I do an ajax call, yet there is no problem going to the URL directly at http://imgfave.com/gragland/rss.

You can see the issue by clicking the link on my test page: http://imgfave.com/ajaxtest

The error page says: "The requested address '/gragland/rss' was not found on this server".

Why would CakePHP have a problem returning the page only when fetched via ajax?

Comment: I presume you're using the ajax helper?

Comment: I'm not using the ajax helper, or at least it's not included in the controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to FireBug, the main difference between the requests is:

```
X-Requested-With XMLHttpRequest
```

From AJAX request.

P.S.: After a quick test using the same headers, it retrieves the RSS without error

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a view file. An html request will return without error without a view. But AJAX request returns 404.